# Why can't I connect to SQLCE/IIS web service when there is no network connection on the desktop?

Tags: web-services, iis, sql-server-ce, merge-replication

I have a Windows CE 5 device that I connect through USB to a Desktop. On the desktop is the SQLCE replication(?) web service/dll (Merge Replication Agent). It's installed properly as far as I know-- the test on the desktop to localhost/sqlce/sqlcesa35.dll works as it should. I plug in the mobile device and try to connect to the web service, but it only connects when the desktop has a network connection-- that is, if a LAN cable is plugged in.

Why is this so and how can I make it connect even without a network on the desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Microsoft loopback adapter https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2777200?wa=wsignin1.0